# Volume keys events while a menu is showing

Tags: android

I have overridden onKeyDown/onkeyUp for one of my activities in order to capture the Volume keys press events and manipulate the sound of the application. However I've noticed that while a menu (be it options menu or context menu ) is activated then I can't no longer capture the volume keys press events. How could this be by passed ?

PS I guess in larger sense this could refer to all keys not only the volume ones

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss

```
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

Comment: Do you mean that the function " public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)" is responsible for handling key events  ?

Comment: onOptionsItemSelected , it should return true,If you handled the event. If you want to allow the event to be handled by the next receiver, return false.

Comment: Yeah, but I was talking about key events